# Align and onslide on beamer don't cope well with the dynamic option

Tags: beamer, align, transition

I'm having trouble with some math formula in an align environment

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
\onslide<1->{aa = & bb \\}
\onslide<2->{ = & cc \\}
\onslide<3->{ = & dd}
\end{align*}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code makes disappear/appear only the = symbols.
Deleting the \setbeamercovered{dynamic} option, everything works as intended, but the opaque preview of next lines disappear.

### Does anybody know a workaround without omitting the dynamic option?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's not going to solve the underlying problem, but `align` is designed to have the `&` *before* the signs of relation, as `aa &= bb`.  moving the `&` will correct the uneven spacing around the equal sign(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only reproduce your problem with xelatex, both with lualatex and pdflatex from texlive2017 it works fine. So the workaround would be to use an up to date lualatex if the font is important to you or an up to date pdflatex if the font does not matter.

---

My suggestion is to keep the `\onslide` within a single cell, this will give you a better spacing around the `=`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
\onslide<1->{aa & = bb \\}
&\onslide<2->{= cc} \\
&\onslide<3->{= dd}
\end{align*}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I compiled with pdflatex
      pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1

Comment: @user49870 Can you update to TL 2017?

Comment: your second solution worked anyway